# What does 'gained appreciably' mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading 'The Wonder That Was India' by A.L.Basham. In Chapter 1, Introduction the author speaks about the vastness and benefit of the Ganges basin. He adds,

> Though generations of unscientific farming, deforestation, and other factors have now much reduced its fertility, this was once among the most productive lands in the world, and it has supported a very large population ever since it was brought under the plough.  At its mouth in Bengal the Ganga forms a large delta, which even in historical times has **gained appreciably on the sea;** here the Ganga joins the Brahmaputra, which flows from Tibet by way of valley of Assam, the eastermost outpost of Hindu culture.

Answer (score 1):

It means an increase that can be measured / perceived.  See [definition of 'Appreciable'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appreciable).

In the passage the delta could be seen getting larger and larger.

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I would assume it means something like "has come noticeably closer to the sea". The phrasal verb "to gain on [something]" means "to come nearer to [something]", often used in the context of a race - to come nearer to an opponent.

The construction is a little odd to be fair. I find it a little strange to say that a delta is getting closer to the sea, since river deltas are generally already close to the sea, although I could evsisage them extending further into the sea over time as more sediment is depositied.  It could have been written better in my opinion, although I may be just splitting hairs.